# How to align tags side by side?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I tried

```
<div>
  <tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white">Home</h1></ins></tr>
  <tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white">Contact</h1></ins></tr>
</div>
```

resulting in

## Home

## Contact

How can I align these tags side by side?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
{
  display: inline-block
};
```

Comment: div><tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white">Home</h1></ins></tr> <tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white"> Contact</h1></ins></tr> </div> This is the code i tried your suggestion but its not working : C –

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: (@DexterHecali: when presenting markup here, it is safer to  enclose in `\`` "backticks" to indicate code.)

Answer (score 0):

either `display:inline` or `float:left` which gives more control (but needs `<div style="clear:both"></div>` afterwards)

```css
h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
before
<nav>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>world</h1>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</nav>
after
```

Comment: <div><tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white">Home</h1></ins></tr> <tr><h1><ins><font face ="bold" color = "white">
  Contact</h1></ins></tr>
 </div>
This is the code i tried your suggestion but its not working : C

Comment: Well that changes everything, they are (how horrible) in a `table`. Also malformed one. You should add this code to the original question.

Comment: (Well, the code *was* in the question, just not visible.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
before
<nav>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>world</h1>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</nav>
after
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you might benefit from a review of your markup.

Certainly you *shouldn't* be using multiple `<h1>` elements within a single document.

The `<h1>` is the principal heading of the entire document. By definition that means there will only ever be one.

Whenever you want to change the *visual presentation* of an element, you will use **CSS**.

---

### HTML Structure

If you are building a **navbar**, then you can use:

- `<ul>` - an *unordered list*

and nest this inside a:

- `<nav>` - a *navigation element*

---

### CSS Presentation

Once you have a structure like the outline above, there are multiple ways to align elements side-by-side:

- `nav ul { display: flex; }`
- `nav ul { display: table; }`
- `nav ul li { float: left; }`
- `nav ul li { display: inline-block; }`

When starting out, one of the simplest ways is to use the last option immediately above:

```
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
nav {
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 96px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```